# set transparency not working, provide a identifyer

Tags: java

im really new to java and when i run my code i get identifyer expected, whats up with that?

import greenfoot.*;  // (World, Actor, GreenfootImage, Greenfoot and MouseInfo)

/**

- Write a description of class battle here.
- 
- @author (your name)
- @version (a version number or a date)
  */
  public class battle extends MyWorld
  {
  public void setTransparency(int 0);

  /**

  - Constructor for objects of class battle.
  - 

  */
  public battle()
  {

  ```
   prepare();
  ```

  }

  /**

  - Prepare the world for the start of the program.
  - That is: create the initial objects and add them to the world.
    */
    private void prepare()
    {
    }
    }

Comment: You'll need so show actual code, not a template with nothing filled in.

Comment: like this? MyWorld { public void setTransparency(int 0);